Agent does not start automatically after reboot
On my oracle db server, I'm using linux 8.9.
How do I get my emctl agent to start automatically after a reboot, as it does on other servers that I have.
It was advised from oracle to add a sleep command to the gcstartup file, as that did not help, nor it was applied on a working server.
I tried to comparing other working servers and they seemed identical, what do you think I should check in this case.
Please let me know if this question is a better suit on a different community.
